# Open a new form and open saved image file from the database c#

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement

I have a database which is linked to my c# app. When the user clicks view a switch statement checks what the file type is a displays the relvant viewer. When its a image I want a new form to open and this image to be displayed. The image is saved in the varribale ofdSelectPicture and I have tried this in the new form

```
picShowPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(ofdSelectPicture.FileName);
```

but that doesnt seem to do anything. So im guessing its the case statement where i need to tell it to open.

So what I'm after is when the user clicks view for a new form to oepn and the image file path which is saved to show the image. this is the switch statement

```
       switch (textBox5.Text)
        {
            case "Picture":
                picture_viewer picture_viewer = new picture_viewer();

                picture_viewer.Show();
                break;

            case "Video":
                MessageBox.Show("video working");
                break;

            case "Audio":
                MessageBox.Show("audio working");
                break;

            case "URL":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(textBox1.Text);
                break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the `pictureBox` object to be public and then set the `.Image` property before showing the form, its better to do that using a method declared inside your `picture_viewer` form

```
public void SetImage(string fileName)
{
   // Set the size of the PictureBox control.
    //this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(140, 140);
    this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
}
```

then

```
switch (textBox5.Text)
{
   case "Picture":
         picture_viewer picture_viewer = new picture_viewer();
         picture_viewer.SetImage(ofdSelectPicture.FileName)
         picture_viewer.Show();
   break;
```

Comment: The path is not of a legal form. is the error when debugging.

Comment: That means that your filename for your picture is incorrect.  Try adding a MessageBox inside your switch statement, just before you run the SetImage Method, have the messageBox display your filename to ensure it is infact a valid filename.   MessageBox.Show(ofdSelectPicture.FileName);